# How to find the Inverse CDF of a Skewed Normal Distribution

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution

The [Wikipedia article on the distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution) also doesn't seem to specify any formulae on right hand side. Also [wolframalpha says](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=InverseCDF%5BSkewNormalDistribution%5Bx,%20w,%20%CE%B1%5D,p%5D) there is no closed form solution.

Comment: I haven't worked it out, but perhaps there is something useful at http://www.apesimulator.org/help/models/rain/Skewed_normal_distribution.html , since it appears that the author is trying to use the inverse distribution method to generate random variates? Or alternatively, use a numerical nonlinear equation solver to numerically determine the inverse for a given argument.

Comment: I used wolfram alpha (also updated in the question), it couldn't find any closed form solution.

Answer (score 1):

The inverse of the CDF is the quantile function. There is no closed form solution but it is already implemented in the R package `sn`. The way the package calculates the quantile of interest is by solving the non-linear equation $F(q) = p$ numerically.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sn/index.html

> Description
>
> Density function, distribution function, quantiles and random number
>   generation for the skew-normal (SN) and the extended skew-normal (ESN)
>   distribution.
>
> Usage
>
> dsn(x, xi=0, omega=1, alpha=0, tau=0, dp=NULL, log=FALSE) psn(x, xi=0,
>   omega=1, alpha=0, tau=0, dp=NULL, engine, ...) qsn(p, xi=0, omega=1,
>   alpha=0, tau=0, dp=NULL, tol=1e-8, solver="NR", ...)  rsn(n=1, xi=0,
>   omega=1, alpha=0, tau=0,  dp=NULL)