# Parametrization of a skew-normal distribution such that negative part is constant

Tags: distributions, skewness, constraint, skew-normal-distribution

I was wondering, how the parameters of the skew-normal distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution) would be constrained when I require that a constant part of its support is in the negative range, i.e.,

$$\int_{-\infty}^0 p(x; \xi, \omega, \alpha)\, dx=a.$$

In other words, how can I determine which set of parameters would result in $a=0.1$?

Comment: Just spotted this related question:https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/224318/how-to-find-the-inverse-cdf-of-a-skewed-normal-distribution

Answer (score 1):

There'll be a space of solutions; with 3 parameters you should end up with some 2D surface.

As it says at the Wikipedia page, the cdf of the skew normal is 
$$F(x;\alpha,\xi,\omega) =\Phi \left({\frac  {x-\xi }{\omega }}\right)-2T\left({\frac  {x-\xi }{\omega }},\alpha \right),$$ 
where $T$ is [Owen's $T$-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Owen%27s_T_function). The $T$ function can be calculated pretty readily; there's references with algorithms and links to code.

I'm pretty sure this cdf is not going to have a closed form inverse, so you'll be using iterative methods to find roots of $F(0;\theta)-\alpha=0$, where $\theta$ is the vector of parameters. You may be lucky enough to find code that does the inverse cdf for the standard case, but I haven't seen one. If you do the problem is relatively simple. [Edit: It looks like both R and Python offer an inverse cdf function. In the case of R `sn:::qsn`; in the case of Python see scipy.stats, specifically `skewnorm.ppf`.]

Note that if there's a solution to $\Phi(t)-2T(t;\alpha)=a$ (i.e. the standard version of the distribution with $\xi=0,\omega=1$) then for any $\omega>0$, $\xi=-\omega t$ will be a solution to the original problem (because when $z=0$, $\frac{z-\xi}{\omega}=t$). Consequently, you can generate a 1-D space of solutions directly from solutions to the "standard" form of solving the inverse-cdf problem in $t$ given $\alpha$ -- i.e. finding solutions to $F(t;\alpha)=a$.

So the approach for some given $a$ would be to find the range of $\alpha$ values which have *some* $t$ for which $F(t;\alpha)=a$ is true, and for each desired $\alpha$ find the corresponding $t$ (this will be a curve relating $t$ to $\alpha$ for some set of values of $\alpha$, and then generate a set of $\omega,\xi$ values as above to solve the original problem you posed, yielding a 1-D linear subspace in  $\omega,\xi$ for each $\alpha$ you want to consider (say over some grid within the possible range of $\alpha$ values.

Answer (score 0):

There is no unique solution. I would suggest fixing the location and scale parameters and finding the skewness parameter numerically. This can be done in R as the skew normal distribution is implemented in the R package `sn`.

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sn/index.html

For example, by fixing $\xi=0, \omega = 1$ we obtain,

```
library(sn)
# desired probability level
p0 <- 0.1
# instrumental function to find the skewness parameter
tempf <- Vectorize(function(alpha0) psn(0, xi = 0, omega = 1, alpha = alpha0) - p0)
# finding the root
root <- uniroot(tempf,c(-5,5))
# checking the probability
psn(0, xi = 0, omega = 1, alpha = root$root)
```

You can apply the same idea to other types of skew-normals, like the asymmetric normal or two-piece normal using the R package `twopiece`.

https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=2149

```
library(twopiece)
# desired probability level
p0 <- 0.1
# instrumental function to find the skewness parameter in (-1,1)
tempf <- Vectorize(function(alpha0){ptp3(x = 0, mu = 0,  par1 = 1, par2 = alpha0, param = "eps", FUN = pnorm) - p0} )
# finding the root
root <- uniroot(tempf,c(-0.99,0.99))
# checking the probability
ptp3(0,  0,  1, root$root, param = "eps", FUN = pnorm)
```